# How to minimize Eclipse PyDev Console output / tracing

Tags: eclipse, ironpython, pydev

I have multiple installations of Eclipse(2021-12) + PyDev(9.3.0.202203051235) all using Iron Python(2.7). All running on Windows 10. They all run the scripts as expected, but one installation has a much more robust console output when debugging, almost like a tracing option is enabled.  I've tried reinstalling, deleting workspaces, deleting '.metadata' folders, etc.  All the project settings seem identical.

Any ideas how to minimize the console output?  Something in registry?

**Expected Console output:**

```
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 15312)
```

**Actual Console output:**

```
1.99s - Using GEVENT_SUPPORT: False
0.00s - Using GEVENT_SHOW_PAUSED_GREENLETS: False
0.00s - pydevd __file__: C:\\Eclipse-2021-12-R\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_9.3.0.202203051235\pysrc\pydevd.py
0.11s - Initial arguments: (['C:\\Eclipse-2021-12-R\\plugins\\org.python.pydev.core_9.3.0.202203051235\\pysrc\\pydevd.py', '--multiprocess', '--protocol-http', '--print-in-debugger-startup', '--vm_type', 'python', '--client', '127.0.0.1', '--port', '60413', '--file', 'C:\\Test.py'],)
0.00s - Current pid: 8884
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 8884)
```

Answer (score 0):

Those should only appear if you add an environment variable asking it to be shown.

i.e.: Something as:

- `PYDEVD_DEBUG=1`
- `PYDEV_DEBUG=1`

Maybe you have such an environment set in your launch configuration or interpreter configuration or elsewhere in your system?

You may want to check the `os.environ` of the running program to see what's set there.

Comment: Thank you!  PYDEVD_DEBUG env variable was set on one machine.  Many thanks!